# Skip a specific package when rebuilding vendor directory with "composer update"?

Tags: composer-php

Is there a way to skip a certain package from being installed as a dependency (based on 2-3 packages that I am installing in composer) when running "composer update"?

As in, I have the following in my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "facebook/php-business-sdk": "^12.0",
    "infusionsoft/php-sdk": "1.5.2",
    "php": ">=7.3",
    "php-http/curl-client": "^2.2.1"
},
```

but 2 of those packages have a requirement for "laminas/laminas-diactoros" package (in their own packages / composer.json config files), and that package is causing quite a conflict for us with our existing code (that uses a similar zend library with same functions).

So is there a way to specify this in composer.json somehow, which packages NOT to install whatsoever and skip during the update/rebuild?

Comment: Why not use the `conflicts` section for that? But keep in mind that this might lead to the situation where other packages can not be installed. If `infusionsoft/php-sdk` requires `laminas/laminas-diactoros`, it requires that package to be present

Comment: Also, if you are facing any problem with `laminas/laminas-diactoros`, why not report this as a bug to the maintainers of that package?